# Executing command from ssh host to client

Tags: ssh

I have a graphical python application running in a server. Some users access the application locally but some access it via ssh with -X option enabled.

When a certain option of the application is enabled, it calls for a browser in a specific webpage trough

> os.system("firefox '{}'".format(url)

Although the browser graphically appears in the client machine, it is actually being executed by the application in the host, so we are having trouble because when too many clients access the machine it consumes too much processing.

I want to, whenever detecting that the application is being run by an ssh session, the browser process is spawned in the client machine, not in the host.

Is it possible? If positive, how?

Comment: The application realistically cannot tell where its display is being presented and the server does not have privileges to open applications on the client. I don't think that what you're asking for is possible. To probe more extreme cases, if the URL is "file://blah", should the file be local to the server or the client? Is the network set up to where the server has access to certain hosts that the client cannot get to? Is `firefox` always installed on the clients? etc.

Comment: "_Although the browser graphically appears in the client machine, it is actually being executed by the application in the host_" - that's almost certainly how your graphical python application is running too. It's normal for X Windows applications

Comment: @doneal24 the url is not in the format "file://blah". Its a site external to both server and client, but hosted in the same subnet. Firefox is always installed on the client, yes. Both server and clients have access to the same hosts, always. It makes sense that the server doesnt have access to open applications in the client. If that is an absolute answer, i think it solves my case.

Comment: @roaima thanks for the clarification. I didnt mean to express that as a particularity of the application, just as one of the main causes of my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead df the python app calling Firefox with the URL, it should call a shell script with the URL.  The shell script will determine if a local browser should be started based on hostname , logon information, environment, etc and if local I runs Firefox locally otherwise it tries to ssh back to the client and run the Firefox command.  Its a bit of work and requires some sort of trust from the server back to the client.  The best the python app could do otherwise is detect it is running remotely, and pop up a dialog telling the user to paste an URL into a local browser

Comment: Yeah, i thought about the ssh back to client thing but i cant guarantee all my users will be an ssh server and i definitely dont have all their ssh passwords. But i agree that would be one way of doing it.
Unfortunately i think the best option for now is the copy-paste one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** No unless you can redesign the program.

AFAICT, the program is suitable for being used on a user's computer at the very least on a linux distro with a desktop environment.

I can only speculate that the program either takes too long to finish, uses lots of resources, or does not support Windows to justify its use over SSH. And even then I suspect your user base is not using TMUX, so it probably is due to resources.

I can't tell the real reason; but if you want to spare resources on the server, easiest way is to make users run the program only locally or in virtual machine/WSL2. You certainly knew that already.

**Theoretical answer:** If you can implement or request a rewrite/adaptation of the python program (that's a big if), move it into server-client model. Run graphical interface locally (front-end) and make requests to the server side (back-end) for (presumably) faster calculations over there. And while at it maybe implement the whole thing as a web app and have just Firefox being enough.

Comment: Thanks! Your assumptions are basically correct: it doesnt support windows and it does consume lots of resources. Reimplementing it in client-server mode would be very troublesome and i intend to move to web application as soon as possible, so the effort i would need to reimplement it would be best spent reimplementing it as a web app already.